# How to apply my function to all list items "li class" on page in eBay Scraper

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to python and BeautifulSoup.

I'm having trouble applying my function to all the list items (li class) on this eBay sold items page.

**Each sold listing is displayed as an li class.** Below is the URL.

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=2017+patrick+mahomes+psa+10+auto&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_ipg=100

Here is my code...

```
def rookie_card_info(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    soup = bs(r.content)
    
    contents = soup.prettify()
    
    rookie_card_list = soup.find_all(class_="srp-results srp-list clearfix")
    
    #How to to apply to all list items
    
    display_image = soup.find(class_="s-item__image-img")
    img_src = display_image.get('src')
    test = Image(img_src)
    display(test)
    print(img_src)

    display_card = soup.find(class_="s-item__link")
    card_title = display_card.find("h3")
    get_card_title = card_title.text
    print(get_card_title)

    display_sold_price = soup.find(class_="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary")
    card_sold_price = display_sold_price.find("span")
    sold_price_text = card_sold_price.find(class_="POSITIVE")
    print(sold_price_text.string)

    display_sold_date = soup.find(class_="s-item__ended-date s-item__endedDate")
    card_sold_date = display_sold_date.string
    print(card_sold_date)
    
rookie_card_info("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=2017+patrick+mahomes+psa+10+auto&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_ipg=100")
```

I wrote the below line of code in an attempt to identify the specific class on the page that encompasses all **li class** objects on the sold results page (there are about 65 results).

```
rookie_card_list = soup.find_all(class_="srp-results srp-list clearfix")
```

When I print the html from this line of code. It contains all of the correct html I would need to parse for my data.

**The data I am parsing for is the image URL, title, sold date, and sold price.**

I get the correct data as shown below...

```
https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/2BwAAOSwETVfzAFT/s-l225.jpg
2017 Armed & Dangerous Patrick Mahomes Auto MINT Condition PSA 10? Rookie Signed
$2,500.00
Dec-27 12:46
```

However, I only get the data from the very first "li class" listing on the page. and not the data for all 65 results.

**Question:**

**What can I do to get data for all 65 results. I need a "plug in and play" solution that I can apply to different URLs.**

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write the full answer for you. Instead, give pointers:

1. To get a list of cards:

   `rookie_card_list = soup.select('.s-item')`

then loop over each item within that:

```
for current_card in rookie_card_list:
```

2. Re-write your function to work off the `current_card` whilst looping i.e. have soup generated by a separate function then have another function which specifically takes in your current card and returns a list of the items you want from that card (perhaps to then add to an overall global list you later turn to a dataframe?). Add in any error handling e.g. if not found what to return?

E.g.

```
def items_from_current_card(current_card):
    card_title = current_card.find("h3").text
    # etc
    return [card_title, ......]
```

3. There are rarely *plug and play* answers with web-scraping I'm afraid. It is for you to work out a generic enough solution to work over as many pages as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up creating 3 different functions as 'get_data(url)' , 'parse(soup)', and 'output(productstlist)'. I was able to parse all of the data I wanted to collect from the second function, and save my data as a CSV with the third.